# Is there a way to grab a list of the users flagged by Microsoft Graph API in controlScore description?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to grab a list of the users flagged by Microsoft Graph API in controlScore description?

I am referring this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/controlscore?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
returns
{
  "controlName": "String",
  "score": "Double",
  "controlCategory": "String",
  "description": "String"
}
```

For example, i have:

controlname:
MFARegistrationV2

Description:
Multi-factor authentication (MFA) helps protect devices and data that are accessible to these users. Adding more authentication methods, such as the Microsoft Authenticator app or a phone number, increases the level of protection if one factor is compromised.  You have 11 out of 2095 users registered and protected with MFA.

score: 0

controlcategory: Identity

I would like to be able to retrieve a string or list identifying the 11 users that were flagged as unsafe by MFARegistrationV2.

@SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I'm already using that. The problem we're running into is that the number of entries with isMfaRegistered is not the same number as being reported in the "You have 11 out of 2095 users registered and protected with MFA." controlScore MFARegistrationV2 description.

What I'm really looking for is with these controlscore controlnames below,

AdminMFAV2
DLPEnabled
IntegratedApps
ManyAdmins
OneAdmin
RoleOverlap
PWAgePolicyNew
InactiveAccounts
BlockLegacyAuthentication
SigninRiskPolicy
UserRiskPolicy
MFARegistrationV2
SelfServicePasswordReset
PasswordHashSync
CustomerLockBoxEnabled
IRMDocs
TLSDeprecation

Is there some kind of graph api query that i can obtain a list of the flagged items?

For example I want to pass in AdminMFAV2 and if the description says "You have 2 out of 6 users registered and protected with MFA." get back a list of "CharlieAcc, BobAcc, TimAcc, DonaldAcc" (the 4 user accounts that are lacking MFA)

Another example would be I want to pass in InactiveAccounts and if the description says "You have 217 accounts that have not been used in the last 30 days." and get back a list of the 217 flagged accounts.

Comment: Filter for users who are registered for MFA. For example: `/reports/credentialUserRegistrationDetails?$filter=isMfaRegistered eq true`.Please let us know if it helps

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity I'm already using that. The problem we're running into is that the number of entries with isMfaRegistered true is not matching up with the controlScore MFARegistrationV2 description.

I want to pass in controlname AdminMFAV2 and for "You have 2 out of 6 users registered and protected with MFA." get back a list of "CharlieAcc, BobAcc, TimAcc, DonaldAcc" (the 4 user accounts that are lacking MFA)

Or pass in controlname InactiveAccounts and if description is "You have 217 accounts that have not been used in the last 30 days." get back a list of the 217.